# Unable to create an External Hive table using an existing Hive table in Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, external-tables

I am trying to create an external table using existing hive table from a spark shell.
(This works fine in beeline/Hive shell but unable to do it in Spark Shell)

`spark.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_db.new_table LIKE old_db.old_table")`

```
== SQL ==
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_db.new_table LIKE old_db.old_table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:643)
  ... 49 elided
```

Even tried Hive Context like below

`import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;`

`val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)`

`sqlContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_db.new_table LIKE old_db.old_table")`

```
== SQL ==
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_db.new_table LIKE old_db.old_table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:643)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
  ... 49 elided
```

if I try to create regular internal table and then change the property to make it external like below

`spark.sql("ALTER TABLE new_db.new_table SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')")`

then I face below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot set or change the preserved property key: 'EXTERNAL';
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.verifyTableProperties(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$alterTable$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:567)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.alterTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:563)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.alterTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.alterTable(SessionCatalog.scala:358)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableSetPropertiesCommand.run(ddl.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:643)
  ... 49 elided
```

Appreciate any suggestion to clone existing hive table as external table in Spark Shell

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE new_db.new_table SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE')")
```

It works only if **new_db.new_table** is non transactional internal/managed table.
It Is possible to copy the data files from the Hive data location to the location you planned to store your external table, drop the table and re-create it as external.

Answer (score 0):

Spark [decides itself](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/tables.scala#L115) to create an external or a managed table, if you specify `location` or not.

```
 *   CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
 *   LIKE [other_db_name.]existing_table_name
 *   [USING provider |
 *    [
 *     [ROW FORMAT row_format]
 *     [STORED AS file_format] [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)]
 *    ]
 *   ]
 *   [locationSpec]
 *   [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, ...)]
```

Then spark and hive syntax differ, but both support the feature

- [hive syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362061#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable)
- [spark syntax](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-like.html)

Now I see two other ways:

1. Run your query from jdbc/python hive driver
2. Use spark code below

```scala
val df = spark.read.table("old_db.old_table").limit(0)
df.write.format("whatever").option("path"' "thenewpath").saveAsTable("new_db.new_table")
```

This will create the table ddl within the hive metastore. You might also partition the table if needed.